# Why Long number in typescript has a wrong value?

Tags: typescript, long-integer

I have number:

```
const lngNumber: number = 44495442002226675;

console.log(lngNumber); // ->gives me 44495442002226670
```

I have no idea why? Btw, this is api response. Somehow the browser does not know how to display this but Postman does.

UPDATE
Raw view from api response is ok, number is correct, "pretty" view is not, it is wrong.

Comment: Hint: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks. Post it as the answer so I can accept it.